# Changing a Hotseat Human Player to AI

Tags: civilization-5

If I'm playing a hotseat multiplayer game with a bunch of friends, and one has to leave, is there a way to make AI take over that friend's play, in the middle of the game?

Comment: pretty sure I know how gonna try it really quick.

Comment: sorry, didn't work. Probably gonna have to look through the config files to change it if that's even possible to do with saves.

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing hotseat games for the last week in service of certain achievements, and I've yet to find a way for the AI to take over a human's slot.  It seems as though once the game is set up, you're stuck with however many humans you expected to play when the game started.